# mvn dependency:tree with broken transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

`mvn dependency:tree` is great for listing transitive dependencies.

However, if you have a broken (unavailable) dependency pulled in by one of your explicit dependencies in your POM, any maven goal (including `dependency:tree`) will fail fast, and the build output only says what artifact failed to download, but not which of your dependencies uses it.

I know that IDEs can figure out where broken dependencies are coming from, but is there a pure Maven way?

I'm using Maven 3.1.1.

Comment: Do you mean some artifact you depend on has missing transitive dependencies?

Comment: Yes, hopefully my edit makes the problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `mvn dependency:tree` and it fails fast, you get a build-error report. In that report, at the bottom of the "Missing" section, you should have "Path to dependency", looking something like this:

```
Path to dependency:
      1) your.application:jar:<version>
      2) your.dependency:jar:<version>
      3) the.missing.dependency:jar:<version>
```

"your.application" depends on "your.dependency" which depends on "the.missing.dependency".

Of course, the list might be longer if the missing dependency is lower in the dependency tree.

Comment: I'm not getting "Path to dependency" but instead: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project abc:xyz:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at swank-clojure:swank-clojure:jar:1.4.2 -> cdt:cdt:jar:1.2.6.2 -> org.clojars.gjahad:debug-repl:jar:0.3.1:...`. So while you're right that the information is present, how do I get the output in your answer?

Comment: @coudy This might have to do with the version of maven you are running. What version of maven are you using?